# c++ template programming: how to call type's function?

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to c++ template programming.

What i want to do is to writing a generic container with fixed capacity for a certain property of its items.

```
template <typename T >
    class SinkContainer{

    std::list<T> _buffer;

    int sum(); // i don't know how to implement this :-(
    public:
    void push_back(T a);
}
```

Type `T` could be

```
Class Client{
    public:
    int num_of_accounts;
}
```

or

```
class Supplier{
public:
     int num_of_warehouse
}
```

the container can only contain a `MAX_NUM` of accounts or warehouse, which means everytime we insert into the buffer, we need to sum up current total accounts OR num of wharehouse.

Can anyone suggest a way to write this generic container? should I over-ride + for `Client` and `Supplier`?

Comment: What's the relationship between `SinkContainer` and `Client`/`Supplier`?

Comment: You mean you don't know how to declare the function or you don't know how to refer to property of `T` inside?

Comment: @JanHudec I don't know how to refer to T's members. They have different names, right?

Comment: @ccfenix: Than the answer is simple. Either they must have the same name or there must be a getter for them with always the same name. The getter may be a member or overloaded non-member or even member of helper "trait" class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normally solved using a so-called *traits class.* Basically, you define an adaptor which provides a unified interface for your template to use.

```
// Traits class definition
template <class T>
struct SinkSumTraits;

template <>
struct SinkSumTraits<Client>
{
    static int summand(const Client &c) { return c.num_of_accounts; }
};

template <>
struct SinkSumTraits<Supplier>
{
    static int summand(const Supplier &s) { return s.num_of_warehouse; }
};


// Traits class usage

template <typename T >
class SinkContainer {
    std::list<T> _buffer;

    int sum()
    {
        return std::accumulate(
            _buffer.begin()
            , _buffer.end()
            , 0
            , [](int s, const T &a) { return s + SinkSumTraits<T>::summand(a); }
        );
    }
public:
    void push_back(T a);
}
```

Note: If you don't have C++11 (for the lambda used in `sum()`), simply replace it with some other use of `SinkSumTraits<T>::summand()`.

Comment: You don't need to define template struct when all you need is a function. Just define functions that will be found with ADL or even methods.

Comment: @JanHudec True indeed. At the same time, trait classes are a more generic concept which people learning templates should be aware of.

Comment: @Angew From performance perspective, usage of traits is faster or slower? do you have a rough idea? What I understand is that using derived class is slow due to vtable lookup. Thtat's why i don't want to do it in an OO approach in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: @ccfenix `std::accumulate` has always had a binary operation as an optional last argument. What I used there is a C++11 lambda, as I've mentioned in the Note at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @ccfenix About performance: It's all trivial inline code. Any optimiser worthy of the name will eliminate all function calls involved and produce exactly the same code as if you'd written `a.num_of_accounts` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Write in the classes Client and Supplier a "Getter" method to get the their number property.

this way you could always call the methods and just make the sum

```
int sum(void){
int iSum = 0;
for(std::list<T>::iterator it = _buffer.begin();it!=_buffer.end();++it){
    iSum+=it->GetNum();
}
return iSum;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"Generic container with fixed capacity" is a description of `std::array` (or `boost::array`, depending on which you can use, if any). As for the generic summing, I'm not sure if this operation should be a part of the container. I believe an approach using generic function working on arbitrary STL-style sequence specified by pair of iterators, dispatched by iterators' `value_type` is a cleaner solution. Or, even better, use `std::for_each`. Something along the lines of

```
int extract_number(const Client& c)
{
    return c.num_of_accounts;
}

int extract_number(const Supplier& s)
{
    return s.num_of_wareouse;
}

template <typename Iter>
int sumStuff(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    typedef typename Iter::value_type type;
    int sum;
    std::for_each(begin, end, [&sum](const type& item)
    {
        sum += extract_number(item);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This way, operation and container are decoupled, and we get a neat, parametrically-polymorphic sum function.

Comment: The `extract_number` functions should _not_ be a template. A simple overloaded function will do (C++03 does not even allow explicit specialization on function templates, because it only makes sense in corner cases).

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks for pointing it out. It was ment as more of a sketch than a full, complete solution, though.

Comment: The question asked for a _fixed capacity for a certain property_, not a _fixed number of elements_. The _sum_ is supposed to be bounded, not the size.

Comment: @JanHudec Of course C++03 *does* allow explicit specialisation of function templates. `[templ.expl.spec]` even lists it first, and provides an example in its first paragraph.

Comment: @Angew: Hm, you are right. It does not only allow _partial_ specialization of templates. Still it's rather rare case where one specializes function templates instead of simply overloading them.

Comment: @JanHudec Partial specialisation of function templates is not allowed in C++11 either. Pretty much the only 03/11 difference in function templates (aside from variadics) is C++03 doesn't allow default template arguments for them, C++11 does. But you're 100% correct with "don't specialise, overload."

Answer (score 0):

If you cant modify Client and Supplier - you can achieve what you want using template specialization:

```
template <typename T >
class SinkContainer{

     int getCount(T t);

}
```

Inside .cpp:

```
template<>
int SinkContainer<Client>::getCount(T t)
{
     return t.num_of_accounts;
}


template<>
int SinkContainer<Supplier>::getCount(T t)
{
     return t.num_of_warehouse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use a pointer-to-member, like this:

```
template <typename T, int T::*N>
class SinkContainer {
    bool do_push_back(T const &);
public:
    int sum();
    bool push_back(T const &t) {
        if (sum() + t.*N < MAX_NUM)
            return do_push_back(t);
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

and use it as

```
SinkContainer<Client, &Client::num_of_accounts> clients;
SinkContainer<Supplier, &Supplier::num_of_warehouse> suppliers;
```

but it's very inflexible. The counter has to be an integer data member (it can't be unsigned, or long, or calculated on the fly), and MAX_NUM is hard-coded.

The traits approach gives you more flexibility, since it can do something different for each type: Agnew has already shown this, so I won't repeat it.